# The pip install command installs other modules than I asked for

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-venv

I have a problem with installing modules in the virtual environment. When I install a module, for example, a module request, and then try to type `pip list`, there are several modules that I have never installed before appearing.

This was when I first made it :

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.2.3
setuptools 41.2.0
```

and this is the first module I want to install which is requests:

```
Package    Version
---------- ---------
certifi    2020.6.20
chardet    3.0.4
idna       2.10
pip        20.2.3
requests   2.24.0
setuptools 41.2.0
urllib3    1.25.10
```

I want to create requirements.txt for my application but when I install every module I need, more modules that are not needed appear.

I saw tutorials about virtual environments and I did not find them experiencing this.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: You could remove all the lines corresponding to things you did not manually install. But do not remove pip or setuptools.

Comment: but when I install pip-chill on venv and run it there is pip-chill too after running `pip-chill==1.0.0
pysimplegui==4.29.0
requests==2.24.0` Is it really like that? @xrisk

Comment: Don’t install pip-chill in your virtual environment, install it outside.

Comment: but when I install pip-chill outside of venv and run it it generates site-packages outside of venv ```black==20.8b1
ffmpeg==1.4
flake8==3.8.3
googletrans==3.0.0
instaloader==4.4.4
keyboard==0.13.5``` @xrisk

Comment: Please ignore my earlier comment. Install pip-chill inside the virtualenv environment. You can just remove the `pip-chill` line manually from the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install a package, `pip` will automatically install all dependencies of that package too.

In your case, `requests` depends on `certifi`, `chardet`, `idna` and `urllib3`, so those also get installed. You don't need to list those packages in your `requirements.txt`.

Take a look at [pipdeptree](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree) if you want to visualize the dependencies of your `pip` packages.

---

**Bonus:** there exist dependency managers like [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) which keep track of your project's requirements for you. You might want to take a look at it if you don't want to manually maintain a requirements file in the future.

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure you refer to the right python or pip version first by using

python3
pip3

- Try to uninstall the existing modules by pip uninstall
- Try Anaconda

Answer (score 2):

Those modules are dependencies on `requests` module.
If you want to use this `requests` module you must have those dependencies. Otherwise you'll get an exception `ModuleNotFoundError`: No module named '`urllib3`'.